# What happens if only the initial heap size (Xms) is set and maximum is left unspecified (Xmx)?

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

Say, I set the initial heap size (Xms) to a particular value and do not specify maximum heap size (Xmx). I'm wondering that what that would mean / what the effect of that would be.

I recently realized that I had done that for one of PRs mistakenly. I didn't face any issues. That made me wonder what the effect of this might be.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting here.  Why would this be unusual or a problem?

Comment: If you dont specify neither initial nor max heap size the JVM uses some algorithm to determine both. If you specify an initial heap size then it has the effect of providing a fixed initial heap size and the JVM still uses some algorithm to determine the max heap size.